# How to search for files with exact extension

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I am searching in Windows 10 for `*.vcxproj` in a file explorer window but it is returning files like:

- project1.vcxproj
- project1.vcxproj.user

How can I control this search more accurately?

Comment: The first file should match, right???  The extensionis identical.

Comment: @KeithMiller yes I only want vcxproj-extension files, not filenames containing .vcxproj in the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: after some testing, it seems it doesn't work anymore. But syntax **"*.<extension name>"** seems to be working fine. So I recommend in your case **"*.vcxproj"**.

You can use the syntax **ext:<extension name>**, in your case **ext:.vcxproj**. :) More info [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/cs-cz/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: I  miss MS-DOS :) THanks I hadn't come across this.

Comment: Git bash.exe: `find . -name '*.vcxproj'`

Comment: [Everything by voidtools](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/).